# Solve $f^2(x)=\frac{k}{f''(x)}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

While studying physics I have many time stumbled upon forces that are directly affected by the position of a particle. Moreover given $f(x)$ how could we approach solving the equation:
$$f^2(x)=\frac{k}{f''(x)}$$
I am new to differential equations and I would really appreciate if someone could explain the thinking process and the steps needed to reach a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Such DE has an explicit solution in terms of the exponential of the inverse error function. Set $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$ and switch to a DE for $g(x)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How do you know that $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$ it could $f(x)=e^{x}+x^2$

Comment: You may look at first for positive solutions, and every continuous and positive function can be written as $e^{g(x)}$ for some continuous function $g(x)$. $e^x+x^2$ can be written as $\exp\left(x+\log\left(1+x^2 e^{-x}\right)\right)$, for instance.

Comment: @Jack d'Aurizio I am not sure to follow you because the DE obtained by setting $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$ is $g'(x)^2+g''(x)=e^{-3 g(x)}$ but, having that, can you give a hint about the way to proceed ?

Answer (score 5):

Well, we have that (multiply both sides by $\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)$):

$$\text{f}\left(x\right)^2=\frac{\text{k}}{\text{f}\space''\left(x\right)}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\int\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)\text{f}\space''\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{k}}{\text{f}\left(x\right)^2}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

We get, when we use:

- $$\int\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)\text{f}\space''\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)^2}{2}+\text{C}_1\tag2$$
- $$\int\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{k}}{\text{f}\left(x\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\text{C}_2-\frac{\text{k}}{\text{f}\left(x\right)}\tag3$$

So:

$$\frac{\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)^2}{2}=\text{C}_3-\frac{\text{k}}{\text{f}\left(x\right)}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\int\frac{\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{\text{C}_3-\frac{2\text{k}}{\text{f}\left(x\right)}}}\space\text{d}x=\int\pm1\space\text{d}x=\text{C}_4\pm x\tag4$$

For the intergal, substitute $\text{u}=\text{f}\left(x\right)$:

$$\int\frac{\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{\text{C}_3-\frac{2\text{k}}{\text{f}\left(x\right)}}}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_3-\frac{2\text{k}}{\text{u}}}}\space\text{d}\text{u}\tag5$$

Comment: Why stop here and not compute a primitive in the RHS of (5)? A standard change of variable works...

Answer (score 4):

A general procedure is as follows:
$$f^2(x)=\frac{k}{f''(x)}$$
$$\implies f''(x)=\frac{k}{f^2(x)}$$
$$\implies 2f'\cdot f''(x)=\frac{k}{f^2(x)}\cdot 2f'$$
$$\implies (f'^2)'=-2k\cdot \left(\frac{1}{f}\right)'$$
Where $'$ means first order derivative with respect to $x$ and $"$ means second order derivative with respect to $x$

So integrating, we get
$$f'^2=-\frac{2k}{f}+c$$
$$\implies f'=\sqrt{c-\frac{2k}{f}}$$
$$\implies \frac{df}{\sqrt{c-\frac{2k}{f}}}=dx$$

Can integrate this now?

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Excuse but as I mentioned I am kind of a beginner how did you get from $ 2f'\cdot f''(x)=\frac{k}{f^2(x)}\cdot 2f'$ to $\implies (f'^2)'=-2k\cdot \left(\frac{1}{f}\right)'$?

Comment: @TheNotoriousSc Well differentiate $ f'^2$ and see what you get. Nothing special here. Just practice a lot and you'll also get this.

Comment: Do you think the OP is plausibly able to complete this?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Could you complete the integration because I can't seem to grasp how we can integrate $df$ and $dx$ since they have no meaning outside of their own integral and derivative

Answer (score 1):

Along with the brilliant answer from Jan EerLand.
$$
f''= f'\frac{d}{df}f' = \frac{k}{f^2} 
$$
Sidenote: The first equality is a result of my physics undergrad days.
$$
\frac{d}{df}\frac{f'^2}{2} = \frac{k}{f^2} 
$$
or
$$
\frac{f'^2}{2} = \int \frac{k}{f^2} df  + C = -\frac{k}{f} + C
$$
then you can re-arrange and follow Jan's answer.

Comment: What do you mean by $d/df$ in the first equation ?

Comment: @JeanMarie - I use an "identity" $$\frac{df}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} f' = \frac{df}{dx}\frac{d}{df} f'$$ Which leads to 
$$
f'\frac{d}{df}f'
$$.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't want to bother you, but there is still the $\dfrac{d}{df}$ that doesn't make sense to me: what is the meaning in this context to differentiate with respect to **a function** ?

Comment: No worries - are you happy with the concept of the chain rule? where an example is $\frac{d}{dx}g(u(x)) = \frac{du}{dx}\frac{d}{du}g(u)$?

Answer (score -1):

Putting $y = f(x)$, we have
$$y^{\prime\prime} = \frac{k}{y^2}.$$ 
Now multiplying both sides by $2y^\prime$, we get
$$2y^\prime y^{\prime\prime} =  \frac{2ky^\prime}{y^2},$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\left( \left( y^\prime \right)^2 \right)^\prime  =  \frac{2ky^\prime}{y^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \left( - \frac{2k}{y} \right),$$
which upon integration of both sides gives
$$ \left( y^\prime \right)^2 = c -\frac{2k}{y},$$
where $c$ is an arbitrary constant of integration. So
$$ y^\prime = \left( c -\frac{2k}{y} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}},$$ and therefore 
$$ \frac{y^\prime  }{ \left( c -\frac{2k}{y} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} } = 1,$$
which we can rewrite as 
$$ \frac{ y^\frac{1}{2} y^\prime }{\left( cy - 2k \right)^\frac{1}{2} } = 1, $$
or $$ \frac{1}{c^\frac{1}{2}} \left( \frac{y}{ y - \frac{2k}{c} } \right)^\frac{1}{2} y^\prime = 1.$$
Can you take it from here on?

Comment: This is not correct: $(y^2)' = 2yy'$ not $2y'y''$. You can also see there is something wrong since the solution you find is $y$ being a constant which is not a solution of the original equation.

Comment: @Winther yes, you're right. Thank you for correcting me. Then what is the correct procedure?

Comment: It should be $[(y')^2]'$ instead of $(y^2)'$ so your final equation will be a new differential equation for $y$.

Comment: Why the upvote?